# Missing result in Google Places API

Tags: web-services, google-maps

When using Google Maps to search for a store called "Netto" near some geographic coordinates

http://maps.google.de/maps?q=netto+near+49.046054,8.380787+&hl=de&ll=49.047475,8.379607&spn=0.01194,0.027874&sll=49.046054,8.380787&sspn=0.011941,0.027874&hq=netto&t=m&z=16

I correctly see two results.

However, doing the same search with the Google Places API

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=49.046054,8.380787&radius=1000&sensor=false&keyword=netto&key=[keyremoved]

yields only a single result:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 49.0459950,
               "lng" : 8.3811020
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "51b5bafdd6224ba1721c9708d59aa0ed7f8377e2",
         "name" : "Netto Marken-Discount AG & Co. KG",
         "reference" : "CoQBdwAAALWmu5j28xIY3s9oBL9Vs8vBCmcghvKWlV9HbHysvQgZ4tMmQ_awemt0k9CA3U9KTRa-CMWq1owOZL1cSLOjKIDb8LdHce3yhIJpJ2fsUnsnFFF1b02gnJK5m5e-4E85_5gTrPZhZIDYrrFenrGyBpWLHkYSFfn0Ir3_zOJlKVWeEhC3RsEsXWqDJ1yizMOR0gvVGhREdmbn0G6GYcAsm4jGJxgJeNbLiw",
         "types" : [ "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "Dürerstr. 3b, Karlsruhe"
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

The radius in the query is 1000m which is definitely sufficient (the distance reported by Google Maps is <400m). Changing the keyword-parameter for name doesn't help either.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=49.046054,8.380787&radius=1000&sensor=false&name=netto&key=[keyremoved]

What could I do to get both results?